# What is the process of translating high level language into machine language?

Tags: programming-languages

I didn't think I would have trouble finding information on this, but...

What is the process? What I have learned is contradicting what I am finding.

What I thought:

```
HLL -> Compiler -> Assembly Language -> Assembler -> Machine Code
```

What it seems to be:

```
HLL -> Compiler -> Machine Code
```

1. Does it just depend on the high level language?
2. If that latter is true, how? (If its a big answer, don't worry about it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually assembly language and machine code are quite the same thing, ie each command in assembly language has only 1 translation in machine code and vice verse (check PS)

the only real difference is "human readability"

so both of your paths are correct and both have the same meaning

PS. of course if you translate from machine code into assembly code, all variables names and some other meta data is lost, because this meta data is not actual code, but you still able to convert this "new code" into machine one - and it will provide initial binary executable

Answer (score 1):

Both are relatively accurate/applicable definitions of what a "compiler" does. Strictly speaking, sure, a compiler generally just spits out machine code that gets passed on to an assembler, but at the same time, most people would be surprised if gcc spat out assembly code by default instead of also passing that assembly through an assembler to generate a binary.

This is mostly just an issue of semantics with definitions -- is there an actual concept you're concerned about or are you just wondering about accepted terminology?

Comment: I suppose I am just wondering what I would answer if I were asked this question. After reading all the answers it sounds like I would just say "It depends."

Comment: I'd say it depends on in what context you're asked. I would say "compilation" in general.

Answer (score 1):

This process varies a lot not only on the high level language, but on the compiler. There are probably a lot more steps than you think if you look closely.

Some compilers do indeed go to Assembly Language before Machine Code, but to be honest - they are almost synonyms! Just two ways of expressing the same thing - the translation is really easy. "movl eax, ebx" always becomes the same bunch of binary for the same machine.

Compilers actually tend to compile things to an intermediate language these days - especially ones like `llvm`. LLVM will translate any number of high level languages to the same intermediate language, then run a series of optimizing passes (that end up at basically the same intermediate language), then finally a few passes to move it to the machine specific code. (This is still simplified, there are many passes and several intermediate languages).